# actionscript: DownloadProgressBar and Flex 4 can't find resource bundle

Tags: actionscript, flex4

I am using flex 4 and I want to custom the preloader, but I meet error of DownloadProgressBar. The code:

```
    public class MyPreLoader extends DownloadProgressBar
{
    var progress:ProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
```

Or substitude ProgressBar to Label will produce the same error:

```
Error: Could not find compiled resource bundle 'collections' for locale 'en_US'.
```

Anyone has implemented the custom preloader? I am almost missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding:

[ResourceBundle("")] tag in the source!

Hope this can help others.